# Epstopdf package not working with XeLaTeX in knitr ONLY

Tags: xetex, knitr, epstopdf, rstudio

**Background**

I regularly use knitr in RStudio to typeset LaTeX documents using XeLaTeX with R chunks in them. This had worked fine up until this morning when RStudio stopped recognising that MiKTeX/Texworks was installed so would not compile the LaTeX into a PDF anymore. Uninstalling and reinstalling MiKTeX/Texworks solved the problem.

**Problem**

However, after reinstalling all of my LaTeX packages that I regularly use, I realised that one of them had stopped working : `epstopdf`. My EPS files were no longer appearing in the document. This still happens even after including `--enable-write18` in the arguments for PDFLaTeX and XeLaTeX in the Texworks preferences.

*This problem only occurs when using XeLaTeX in RStudio.*

When using Texworks directly, `epstopdf` works fine. And when using PDFLaTeX in RStudio, it also works fine.

Can anybody tell me what I am doing wrong or why this has suddenly started happening?

**MWE**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=1.1\linewidth]{example1.eps}
  \caption{Example1}
\end{figure}
Copy and paste the following code to convert more images at the same time:
\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=1.1\linewidth]{example2.eps}
  \caption{Example2}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you provide some sample code that one can use in R under knitr? Is this specific to a single image, or all of them?

Comment: HI Werner, sure thing. It happens with all of my eps images. Here is some sample code which doesn't work with knitr using xelatex but works in every other way

`\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{epstopdf}

\begin{document}


\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=1.1\linewidth]{example1.eps}
  \caption{Example1}
\end{figure}

Copy and paste the following code to convert more images at the same time:
\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=1.1\linewidth]{example2.eps}
  \caption{Example2}
\end{figure}

\end{document}`

Comment: You shouldn't need to load `epstopdf` explicitly or use shell escape. But you may need to tell `graphicx` the driver you want to use since this is XeLaTeX and I don't think `graphicx` can always figure it out. (But I'm not certain of this - I might be thinking of something else.)

Comment: Don't include the extension when loading the image with `\includegraphics` unless you are certain you need to do so for special reasons and why.

Comment: Unfortunately removing the .eps and/or specifying it is `XeLateX` to `graphicx` didn't work